# Update multiple records efficiently in code first

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, linq-to-entities

I have the following scenario in an action, where I want to update the quantities of all items in a given cart. I am posting back the array to my controller of my cart items, and want to update the quantities as the user has updated them. How can I achieve this? Here is where I am at.

This is the view for my cart

```
@model SeniorProjectMVC.Models.ViewModels.CartViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h3>Your cart</h3>

@*<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>*@  

<div class="row header-row">
    <div class="large-1 columns">
        <h4> Quantity</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="large-5 columns text-center">
       <h4>Name</h4> 
    </div>
    <div class="large-1 columns">
      <h4>Price</h4>  
    </div>
    <div class="large-2 columns">
        <h4>In stock</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="large-3 columns"></div>
</div>
@{ 
    int CurrentIndex = 1;
}
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.CartArray.Length; i++)
{

    <div class="@(CurrentIndex % 2 == 0 ? "row primary-row" : "row alternate-row")">
        <div class="large-1 columns">
            @Html.EditorFor( m => m.CartArray[i].Quantity)
        </div>
        <div class="large-5 columns text-center">
            @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.CartArray[i].Sku.Product.Name)
        </div>
        <div class="large-1 columns">
            @*@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.CartArray[i].Sku.Product.Price)*@
            @String.Format("{0:c}", (Model.CartArray[i].Sku.Product.Price * Model.CartArray[i].Quantity))
        </div>
        <div class="large-2 columns">
            @( Model.CartArray[i].Sku.Quantity > 0 ? "In Stock" : "Out of stock")
        </div>
        <div class="large-3 columns">
            <ul class="button-group">
                @*<li class="button">@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = Model.CartArray[i].ID }, new { @class = "button primary" }) </li>*@
                <li class="button">@Html.ActionLink("Remove", "Remove", new { id = Model.CartArray[i].ID }, new { @class = "button primary" })</li>
            </ul>

            @*@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.ID }, new { @class = "button primary" }) |*@

        </div>
    </div>
    { CurrentIndex = CurrentIndex + 1; }
}
<div clsas="row">
    <div class="large-offset-8 columns">
        <h5 class="inline">Subtotal:</h5><h4 class="inline">@(Model.CartArray.Sum(p => (p.Sku.Product.Price * p.Quantity)).ToString("c"))</h4>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="medium-offset-8 medium-4 columns">
        <ul class="button-group">
            <li class="button">@Html.ActionLink("Update Quantities", "UpdateQuantities", "Cart", new { array = Model.CartArray }, new { @class = "button primary large" })</li>
            @if (Request.IsAuthenticated && User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                <li class="button">@Html.ActionLink("Checkout", "Address", "Checkout", null, new { @class = "button primary large" })</li>
            }
            else
            {
                <li class="button secondary">You must sign in to checkout</li>
            }

        </ul>   
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the action that I want to post the quantities back to the controller, and then update my database context class. I'm not sure how or what the most efficient way of achieving this is.

```
public ActionResult UpdateQuantities(Models.ViewModels.CartViewModel cartModel)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < cartModel.CartArray.Length; i++)
            {
                //either update each record, or build a list to do one mass update.
                //This is where I am stuck
            }

            return View();
        }
```

Comment: You need to wrap your elements in a form and submit the form to a POST method (and delete your button which is a making a GET and will not send back the your model - look at the `href` attribute it generates to understand - and if it did it would be sending back the original data, not the edited data). You will also need additional hidden inputs to identify the item in the collection.

Comment: So I'd need to wrap them in a form tag and add a hidden field for the ID field for each cart item correct?

Comment: Yes. Any properties of `CartViewModel`, including properties of its `CartArray` collection that you want to receive in the controller will need form controls inside `@using (Html.BeginForm(...))`

Comment: Do you have any examples I could follow? I seem to be having an issue

Comment: What issue are you having?

Comment: I got it to post back with the correct values. I'm simply not sure the best way to update all of the records in my database with the new values. What's the proper way to bulk update records with the new quantities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to go with something like this:

```
public ActionResult UpdateQuantities(Models.ViewModels.CartViewModel cartModel)
{
    // instantiate your database context if it's not already done
    using (var db = new Context())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < cartModel.CartArray.Length; i++)
        {
            // update your records one at a time
            db.YourItems.Where(i => <your_criteria>).Member = NewValue;
        }

        // commit your changes only once at the end
        db.SaveChanges();

        return View();
    }
```

Depending on how your model data are structured, you can also replace the for loop above with something like this:

```
var items = db.YourItems.ToList();
items.ForEach(i => i.Member = cartModel.CartArray[i.Id].NewValue);
```

or if you have to update several properties:

```
items.ForEach(i => {
    i.Member1 = cartModel.CartArray[i.Id].Value1;
    i.Member2 = cartModel.CartArray[i.Id].Value2;
};
```